# Comparison between previous week and current week total sales in powerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I am very new to the PowerBI community and I am confused about how to visualize and create measures/columns for the data which requires comparing last week/month/year data with respect to the current week.

I have tried various solutions available on the internet or other forums. I would appreciate it if anyone can please outline the steps required to achieve the goal.

The data that I have is transactional data and I have also created a Date Table. I am not sure how to go ahead with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create measures like this (for days):

```
PreviousDay = 
var __DayOnRow = SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[day])
return
CALCULATE( SUM(Table[SomethingToSum]), FILTER(ALL(Calendar),Calendar[day] =  __DayOnRow -1 ))
```

How this work:

1. SELECTEDVALUE gets a specific day from the current context
2. __DayOnRow -1 give us a previous Day (not yesterday date< except for today date>)
3. FILTER with ALL, remove every filter on Calendar (current row is also a filter, so without removing filter we get two excluding conditions )

How do that for WEEK?

```
PreviousWeek = 
var __WeekOnRow = SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Week])
var __FirstDayOfWeek = calculate(min(Calendar[Day]), FILTER(ALL(Calendar), __WeekOnRow = Calendar[Week] ))
var __LastDayOfWeek = calculate(max(Calendar[Day]), FILTER(ALL(Calendar), __WeekOnRow = Calendar[Week] ))

return

CALCULATE(SUM(Table[SomethingToSum]), FILTER(ALL(Calendar),Calendar[day] >=  __FirstDayOfWeek -7 &&  Calendar[day] <=  __LastDayOfWeek -7 ))
```